# Prevent SAP from creating spool request when executing in background

Tags: jobs, spool, sap-basis

Is there way so I could remove the creation of spool request when I execute program in background (the standard one--Execute in Background)? I don't want to create spool.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What don't you want to create a spool?

Answer (score 1):

After clicking on Execute in background, at the options popup, give the printer name NULL OR search similar in the printer list.

For additional information, see note:

> 181571 - Output device NULL

It states:

*Similar to /dev/zero on UNIX, the output to a device named NULL has the effect that no data is created in the spool system when you print ABAP lists.*

Comment: Hi @szako , there is no NULL option in my output device, nor I cannot put NULL to it.

Comment: Hi @szako , there is no NULL option in my output device, nor I cannot put NULL to it. Thanks. Kindly let me know how can make NULL entry possible. Simply putting no value or leaving output device blank still generates spool.

Comment: Good answer, but one should keep attention to remark: `Note that this applies only to printing lists and SAPscript.`

Answer (score -1):

Solution is, when you are displaying report/alv in your program, you have to put condition "IF sy-batch IS INITIAL". Inside this condition, put the display report so that when you execute report in Background (SY-BATCH EQ 'X'), it would not generate spool.

Hope this helps to anyone who will experience the same.